# Job Shop Problem with dynamic jobs

Tags: algorithms, optimization, scheduling, planning

I've got a problem at hand that's about scheduling tasks to different ressources, basically a simple job shop problem. But: my tasks "branch" dynamically, that is, there are tasks that not only have a start time parameter but also a parameter that defines how many independently scheduled series of tasks the task shall have as successor. So I kind of have a job shop problem with the number of jobs being part of the solution.

Now the question: how do you call this kind of problems? What do I have to look for to find literature about this?